# how to encrypt and decrypt file while uploading and downloading

Tags: java, spring, file, file-upload, rsa

I need to encrypt the file while uploading and decrypt the file while downloading.

I wrote a logic to upload and download the file in REST spring application but not able to encrypt and decrypt. please check my code

Controller - upload logic

```
    @CrossOrigin(maxAge = 4800, allowCredentials = "false")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/multipleSave/{module}/{reminderId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String uploadMultiple(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] files, 
            @PathVariable String module,@PathVariable int reminderId,
            HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {

        long limit = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
        String fileName = null;
        String msg = "";
        String modulePath="";
        modulePath = path+"/"+module;
        if(files.length > 5){
            throw new FileUploadException("Max number of Files to upload is 5");
        }
        if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                try {
                    if(files[i].getSize() > limit){
                        throw new FileUploadException("File upload Limit is 2 mb, please check the size");
                    }

                    fileName = files[i].getOriginalFilename();
                    String ext =  fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
                    String dateTime = getCurrentDateTime();
                    String localDate = dateTime.toString().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                    String renameFile = fileName.substring(0,fileName.lastIndexOf('.'))+"_"+localDate.toString()+"."+ext;
                    NRICSecurity sec = new NRICSecurity();

                    sec.encrypt(renameFile,modulePath+"/"+renameFile+".enc");


                } catch (Exception e) {
                //Exception
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

renameFile is giving FileNotFoundException, how I can define entire path from MultipartFile

Service - Download logic

```
public void downloadFile(HttpServletResponse response, int fileId) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
       FileUpload fileUpload = fileDAO.getFileByFileId(fileId);
       if (fileUpload != null) {
           try{
           new NRICSecurity().decrypt(fileUpload.getFilePath()+"/"+fileUpload.getFileNameOrg()+".enc", fileUpload.getFileName());
           }catch(Exception e){

           }
           Path file = Paths.get(fileUpload.getFilePath(), fileUpload.getFileNameOrg());
           if (Files.exists(file)) {
               try {
                   String contentType = Files.probeContentType(file);
                   response.setContentType(contentType);
                   response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileUpload.getFileName());
                   Files.copy(file, response.getOutputStream());
                   response.getOutputStream().flush();
               } catch (IOException ex) {

               }
           } else {
               response.sendError(404, new FileNotFoundException().getMessage());
           }
       } else {
           response.sendError(404, new FileNotFoundException().getMessage());
       }
   }
```

encrypt and decrypt method using RSA

```
    //------File Encryption and Decryption---------

    /**
     * Encrypt file
     * @param filename
     * @param outFile
     */
    public void encrypt(String fileName, String outFile){
        String publickeyFile = mybundle.getString("r365.private.key");
        try{
            PublicKey publicKey = readPublicKey(publickeyFile);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
            processFile(cipher,fileName,outFile);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    /**
     * Decrypt File
     * @param filename
     * @param outFile
     */
    public void decrypt(String fileName, String outFile){
        String privateKeyFile = mybundle.getString("r365.private.key");
        try{
            PrivateKey privateKey = readPrivateKey(privateKeyFile);
            Cipher decryptChiper = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            decryptChiper.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
            processFile(decryptChiper,fileName,outFile);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

     private void processFile(Cipher ci,InputStream in,OutputStream out)
            throws javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException,
                   javax.crypto.BadPaddingException,
                   java.io.IOException
            {
            byte[] ibuf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(ibuf)) != -1) {
                byte[] obuf = ci.update(ibuf, 0, len);
                if ( obuf != null ) out.write(obuf);
            }
            byte[] obuf = ci.doFinal();
            if ( obuf != null ) out.write(obuf);
            }

   private void processFile(Cipher ci,String inFile,String outFile)
            throws javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException,
                   javax.crypto.BadPaddingException,
                   java.io.IOException
            {
            try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inFile);
                 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile)) {
                processFile(ci, in, out);
                }
            }
```

the encrypt and decrypt method is working if I pass inFile and outFile with entire path, in upload I am not able to get the path from MultiPartFile[] file and if I try to download it will just download in browser not in the server location.

Comment: in place of fileName while upload I tried passing inputStream = files[i].getInputStream but getting javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 245 bytes. I am using  `KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
              keyGen.initialize(2048);` for key generation. Why down Voted? any suggestion

Comment: HTTPS gives you everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

I used AES key to encrypt and decrypt the file.
Thank you  [novixys](https://www.novixys.com/blog/java-aes-example/)

please find the solution above or message me for more details.